# Trouble making login page?

Tags: php, mysql, http, authentication

Okay, so I want to make a simple login page. I've created a register page successfully, but i can't get the login thing down.

login.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

include("mainmenu.php");

$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usrname']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy");
 if(!$con){
  die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$login = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (usrname = '$usrname' AND password = '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($login);

 if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1 {

    $_SESSION = true;
    header('Location: indexlogin.php');
 }

   else {
echo = "Wrong username or password." ;
}


?>
```

indexlogin.php just echoes "Login successful." What am I doing wrong?
Oh, and just FYI- my database is "users" and my table is "data".

Comment: Well we don't know what's inside of "indexlogin.php", so we really can't help you.

Comment: Can you post the expected result as well?

Comment: like i said- indexlogin.php is:

Comment: <?php echo "Login successful!" ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

session_start();

include("mainmenu.php");

$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usrname']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy");
if (!$con) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die(mysql_error());

$login = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (usrname = '$usrname' AND password = '$password')";
$result = mysql_query($login);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
    header('Location: indexlogin.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Wrong username or password.";
}

?>
```

- <strike>I added `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent [SQL](http://xkcd.com/327/) [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).</strike>
  *No, I didn't because you already had it.*
- I cleaned up the formatting of the code a bit.
- I changed `$_SESSION = true;` (which doesn't make sense) into `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`. Then, in `indexlogin.php` you can do something like `if ($_SESSION['logged_in']) { echo $secret; }`
- I fixed `echo = "Wrong username or password.";` to `echo "Wrong username or password.";`
- I added a closing bracket near `mysql_num_rows($result) == 1`.

---

You said:

> my database is "users" and my table is
>   "data".

If this is correct, you will need to change `SELECT * FROM users` to `SELECT * FROM data`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can set $_SESSION = true, because $_SESSION is an array. Try $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true.