# How to use the md5 hash?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, md5

Okay, so I'm learning php, html, and mysql to learn website development (for fun). One thing I still don't get is how to use md5 or sha1 hashes. I know how to hash the plain text, but say I want to make a login page. Since the password is hashed and can't be reversed, how would mysql know that the user-inserted password matches the hashed password in the database? Here is what I mean:

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$query = ("INSERT INTO `users`.`data` (`password`) VALUES ('$password')");
```

I know that this snippet of script hashes the password, but how would I use this piece of code and make a login page? Any working examples would be great.

Here is my script:

```
<?php  

session_start();  

include("mainmenu.php");  

$usrname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usrname']); 
$password = md5($_POST['password']);  

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "g00dfor@boy"); 

if (!$con) {    
   die(mysql_error()); }  

mysql_select_db("users", $con) or die(mysql_error());  

$login = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE (`usrname` = '$usrname' AND `password` = '$password')"; 

$result = mysql_query($login);  


if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {     

$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;   
  header('Location: indexlogin.php');  

exit; 

} 

else {     
echo "Wrong username or password."; 

}  

?>
```

But I still get the else statement, "Wrong username or password. Someone help plz!"

Comment: Seemingly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642376/trouble-making-login-page

Comment: *use md5 of sha1 hashes* ? I guess you mean *or*?

Comment: @thirtydot I'd simply write "lol" if there wasn't a minimum character count

Comment: maybe i just have to use the fetch_array function.

Answer (score 1):

Please use SHA1/256. MD5 is not cryptographically secure anymore and it's discouraged to use it for cryptography (it's fine for file hashes ETC).

I'm not posting code, but explaining the technique:

First, on the registration, take the SHA1/256 hash of the password and store it in the database. The next time the user logs in you take the SHA1/256 hash of the password he/she entered again and match it against the hash stored in your database. This works because the SHA1 hash for the password is semi-unique (the chances for duplicates are small) for that password.

Comment: Correct... From what I have limited my MD5 hash use for is for binary comparisons between files, such as version checking for ANY differences in files, images, tables, etc.. I may be working with

Comment: yeah i just read Jani's article. "speed is the enemy" as the article says.

Comment: Trust me, speed is NO argument whatsoever for hashing 8-62 character passwords. You're looking into milliseconds or less. The speeds get relevant when comparing the hashes of 4 gigabyte files.

Comment: Please don't use SHA-1.  Although it hasn't been completely broken, several attacks against it have been found and it's quite likely that even more will be over time.  Please use something from the SHA-2 family such as SHA-256 instead.  So far these have been more robust against attacks.

Comment: whatever is more secure. im just trying to get the concept down.

Comment: @Keith Irwin: True, but SHA1 will last at least 5 years before it is broken like MD5 is now. Besides, attacks on password hashes in web applications like Ken is describing aren't that common (I haven't heard of any cases except for million-websites like Yahoo).

Comment: sha1 or md5 or sha256 are all the same when it comes to password hashing.  Each are just as susceptible to rainbow tables.  Now, if you use a salt, that changes things and your comments make sense.  But if you are under the illusion that `hash('sha256', $password)` is anything but trivially better than `md5($password)` you are sadly mistaken (after all, the only thing that changes for the rainbow table is the size of the database since the hash produced by sha256 is much larger than md5)...  Not using a salt is almost as bad as not using a hash...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite simple: You have a hash in the database, so you need to hash the user-provided password to compare them.

So when the user attempts to log in, you take the `$_POST['password']` or whatever, and create a hash of it. Then, you simply query the database for the hash, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = 'hashgoeshere'`

I would also recommend you read more about secure storage of passwords. For example this is a good start: [You're probably storing passwords incorrectly - Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: This reminds me of a nice error message: "You cannot use this password. This password is already in use by user: *Michael*" :)

Answer (score 0):

It hashes the password so it is not save in clear text 
e.g mylongpassword becomes 9a995d3f6a3d69c1a9b4344bed4f2c87

Select the hashed password using the db First

```
$password_from_db = Select * from user where username='".$_POST['username']."'
```

Then password from the  ($_POST['password']) should be hashed first in PHP then compared to the valued stored in the DB

```
<?       
   if (md5($_POST['password'])==$password_from_db){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
?>
```

Comment: i know that- but how would i take the hash and make it when a user enters "mylongpassword" the database can retrieve and recognize "mylongpassword" and be able to log them in? arggh... its so hard to explain...

Comment: i think... i get it... im not sure. let me redo my script.

Comment: Sure the logic is hash the value first before you compare it the value in the DB

Comment: okay so i can do: "$password = md5($_POST['password']); ("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE (`usrname` = '$usrname' AND `password` = '$password')");"? I hashed the password after the plain text was submitted from the form.

Comment: That should work accordingly, If the result of your sql is more than 1 then you have verified the password correctly

Comment: i still dont get it... i hashed my password, but it still does not work. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well instead of inserting into the SQL database, assign some query into a variable and check it against the md5 given by the user

Answer (score 0):

When the user tries to login using their password, you take the md5 of what they enter and compare it with what you've already stored in the database.  If it matches, you know they entered the right password.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**
Your code seems okay.
Check if your **password field** in the database is at least 32 characters.
And try to execute this query (changing variables to real string) in phpMyAdmin if you use one.

Comment: 40? i thought that md5 was 32.

Comment: i dnt know whats wrong- maybe something wrong with the input 'usrname'?

Comment: is there a chance, you created several users with the same username/password combination?

Comment: btw, are your form fields names are usrname and password? Try running this query in phpMyAdmin or mysql shell: SELECT * FROM data WHERE usrname='insert_username_here' AND password=MD5('insert_your_password')

Answer (score 0):

You have a major crypto problem, too.

```
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
```

The problem there is that all the people with identical passwords will have identical hashes, so if (when?) someone breaks into your site, they run one dictionary attack, and then compare the hashes from the attack to the hashes from your DB.  As a result, they break every single account on your site for essentially the same cost as breaking one.

At a very minimum, you should salt it, something like this:

```
$password = md5($_POST['user'] + $_POST['password']);
```

But even that has surprising weaknesses, so it's better to hash it twice, maybe like this:

```
$password = md5($_POST['password'] + md5($_POST['password'] + $_POST['user']));
```

Of course, the best way of all is to use something written by someone who knows far more about doing crypto properly than I do :)

(And remember that bad perf in your authentication system is a feature.)